# class path resource [aa.xlsx] cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system

Tags: java

I have a problem.
When I parse an xlsx file, java throws an error like this.

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [template.xlsx] cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system: jar:file:/data0/webroot/triallesson-msg-iservice/triallesson-msg-iservice.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/template.xlsx ,message = class path resource [template.xlsx] cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system: jar:file:/data0/webroot/triallesson-msg-iservice/triallesson-msg-iservice.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/template.xlsx
2019-05-20 11:31:08.577 ERROR [springAppName_IS_UNDEFINED,,,] [TemplateController] -
```

But I have no problem when debugging locally.Once the jar is uploaded to the server,He has failed

I put xlsx in the resourse directory.

```
    public void addTemplateByExcel() throws Exception {
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:template.xlsx")));
        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Is the template.xlsx bundled inside the jar ?  If not, be aware that the "-cp" parameter on the Java command line is ignored when running jar files.

Comment: thank ! I solved this problem through this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35726500/using-resourceutils-getfile-to-read-a-file-from-classpath-in-heroku-environment